# How can we determine when the "last" worker process/thread is finished in Go?

Tags: go, concurrency

I'll use a hacky inefficient prime number finder to make this question a little more concrete.

Let's say our main function fires off a bunch of "worker" goroutines. They will report their results to a single channnel which prints them. But *not every worker will report something* so we can't use a counter to know when the last job is finished. Or is there a way?

For the concrete example, here, main fires off goroutines to check whether the values 2...1000 are prime (yeah I know it is inefficient).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go func () {
        for {
            fmt.Print(" ", <- c)
        }
    }()
    for n := 2; n < 1000; n++ {
        go printIfPrime(n, c)
    }
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)   // <---- THIS FEELS WRONG
}

func printIfPrime(n int, channel chan int) {
    for d := 2; d * d <= n; d++ {
        if n % d == 0 {
            return
        }
    }
    channel <- n
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to reliably stop it at the right time. I tried adding a sleep at the end of `main` and it works (but it might take too long, and this is no way to write concurrent code!). I would like to know if there was a way to send a stop signal through a channel or something so `main` can stop at the right time.

The trick here is that I don't know how many worker responses there will be.

Is this impossible or is there a cool trick?

(If there's an answer for this prime example, great. I can probably generalize. Or maybe not. Maybe this is app specific?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`WaitGroup`](http://godoc.org/sync#WaitGroup).

The following code uses two WaitGroups.  The main function uses `wgTest` to wait for `print_if_prime` functions to complete. Once they are done, it closes the channel to break the for loop in the printing goroutine. The main function uses `wgPrint` to wait for printing to complete.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "sync"
) 

func main() {
  c := make(chan int)
  var wgPrint, wgTest sync.WaitGroup

  wgPrint.Add(1)
  go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for n := range c {
        fmt.Print(" ", n)
    }
  }(&wgPrint)

  for n := 2; n < 1000; n++ {
    wgTest.Add(1)
    go print_if_prime(&wgTest, n, c)
  }

  wgTest.Wait()
  close(c)
  wgPrint.Wait()
}

func print_if_prime(wg *sync.WaitGroup, n int, channel chan int) {
  defer wg.Done()
  for d := 2; d*d <= n; d++ {
    if n%d == 0 {
        return
    }
  }
  channel <- n
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/iJk9bW5Pei)